Why is the lattice of partitions on a set simple?
In chapter 2, section 8 of A Course in Universal Algebra by Burris and Sankappanavar, exercise 10 reads,

Show that the lattice of partitions $\langle \Pi(A), \subseteq \rangle$ of a set $A$ is a simple lattice.

I have been able to prove this on my own for when $A$ is finite, but not in general, and I cannot find any references or mention of this fact online, although I will admit I'm not particularly good at searching for things like this. At this point I am just curious what the proof is, so that I may learn the techniques used in it for next time.
Here is my proof for finite $A$:
We start with the base case, $M_3$, which happens to be the lattice of partitions on a set of $3$ elements. One can verify this lattice is simple.
Let $0$ denote the partition that is all singletons, and $A_{ij}$ the partitions that have all singletons except for $\{i, j\}$ being one of the parts; these are also known as the atoms of the lattice. Also, let $1$ denote the partition with only one part, $A$ itself.
Suppose we identify a partition $P$ with $0$. If $P = 1$, this identifies everything in the lattice, so we don't care. Otherwise, there's some $i, j$ that live in different parts of $P$, and so $A_{ij} \vee P \sim A_{ij} \vee 0 = A_{ij}$ with $A_{ij} \vee P \neq A_{ij}$, so WLOG we can assume we're identifying non-$0$ partitions.
Now proceed by induction. Suppose we are identifying $P$ and $Q$ with $0 \neq P \subseteq Q$. Let $i, j$ be two elements that live in the same part of $P$. Then $A_{ij} \subseteq P$ and we can define the sublattice $\{X \in \Pi(A) : A_{ij} \subseteq X\}$ in which it belongs; this sublattice is evidently isomorphic to the lattice of partitions on a set with one less element, in particular $A/A_{ij}$.
We therefore have to identify every partition in this sublattice. But then, one of these partitions in this sublattice is $A_{ij} \vee A_{ik}$ for some $k \neq i, j$, by assumptions on the size of the set we're partitioning. (We need this sublattice to be on a set with size at least $3$, so $A$ must have at least $4$ elements for this argument to go through.) We can apply a similar argument to identify everything above $A_{ik}$, but then we have $A_{ij} \sim A_{ij} \vee A_{ik} \sim A_{ik}$, and we have $A_{ij} \sim 1 \sim A_{ik}$, so we have $1 \sim A_{ij} \land A_{ik} = 0$, as desired.
As you can see, this proof hinges on $A$ being finite. I have no idea for how to extend a proof like this to infinite $A$, so I suspect I have to use a different trick. It also has a lot of annoying casework, so it would be nice if the proof were more streamlined; in particular, I'm hoping there is some beautiful trick I'm failing to spot here.

Do you have access to the book General Lattice Theory, by Grãtzer? The proof is there, chapter IV. Modular and semimodular lattices §4. Partition Lattices.

Can you please add the definition of a simple lattice?

@MartinBrandenburg Similar to what happens in other types of algebras, even if with a different guise, a lattice $L$ is simple if its only congruence relations are $$\Delta_L={(x,x):x\in L}$$ and $\nabla_X=L^2$.

@amrsa I could search my university library or do... what one often does to get access to a text, but I figure that even if it's there, you could reproduce it for the benefit of others reading this question in the future. Although I don't know what MSE culture says about this kind of thing.

@amrsa sounds good. I am curious the ways I'm being unclear in my proof. I want to become better at being understood / comprehensible, so this feedback would be very useful to me. (But I'm aware MSE isn't a verification website so I understand if you don't wanna.)

@Keith Maybe saying it's confusing is not the best wording for it. It may be a matter of taste, concerning the notation, and that may depend on the background. Anyway, I added it for the sake of completion. Let me know if you find something unclear, since I copied from a text of mine and could, for example, add some typos. Also, if I'm using some result you don't know about (I think this could only be that the lattice is atomistic, but that is easy to prove).

I'll use the notation $\Delta_A$ to denote the equivalence relation $\{(a,a):a \in A\}$ and likewise for the associated partition (in which every block is trivial), and $\nabla_A$ to denote $A^2$ and the associated partition (which has only one block).
Concerning congruences, I'll use, sometimes the notation $x \equiv_{\theta} y$ with the meaning of $(x,y) \in \theta$.
Let us start with two useful claims:
Claim 1.
If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are atoms of $\Pi(A)$, then there is $\gamma \in \Pi(A)$ with is complement of both $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
If $\alpha$ is an atom of $\Pi(A)$, then $\alpha$ has a unique non-trivial block, and that block has exactly two elements, like so: $\{a_1,a_2\}$.
Likewise, $\beta$ has one single non-trivial block, $\{b_1,b_2\}$.
If $\{a_1,a_2\} \cap \{b_1,b_2\} = \varnothing$, then the partition $\gamma$ with the blocks $\{a_1,b_1\}$ and $A\setminus\{a_1,b_1\}$ will do it;
otherwise, say the non-trivial blocks of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $\{a,c\}$ and $\{b,c\}$, pick $\gamma$ to have the blocks $\{c\}$ and $A\setminus\{c\}$.
Claim 2.
If $\theta \neq \Delta_{\Pi(A)}$ is a congruence of $\Pi(A)$, and $\pi$ is an atom of $\Pi(A)$, then $\pi \equiv_{\theta} \Delta_A$.
Let $\alpha, \beta \in \Pi(A)$, such that $\alpha \equiv_{\theta} \beta$ and $\alpha < \beta$ and let $\pi$ be an atom such that $\pi < \beta$ and $\pi \nleq \alpha$.
Then
$$\pi = \pi \wedge \beta \equiv_{\theta} \pi \wedge \alpha = \Delta_A.$$
Let $\tau$ be another atom of $\Pi(A)$ and $\gamma$ a comma complement to $\pi$ and $\tau$.
Then
\begin{align}
\pi \equiv_{\theta} \Delta_A
&\implies \nabla_A = \pi \vee \gamma \equiv_{\theta} \Delta_A \vee \gamma = \gamma\\
&\implies \tau = \nabla_A \wedge \tau \equiv_{\theta} \gamma \wedge \tau = \Delta_A.
\end{align}
The finite case.
If $A$ is a finite set, then, since $\Pi(A)$ is an atomistic lattice, we have $\nabla_A = \xi_1 \vee \cdots \vee \xi_n$, where $\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n$ are atoms of $\Pi(A)$.
Since $\xi_i \equiv_{\theta} \Delta_A$, whenever $\theta$ is a non-trivial congruence of $\Pi(A)$, it follows that $\Delta_A \equiv_{\theta} \nabla_A$.
The infinite case.
If $A$ is infinite, then $A = A_0 \cup A_1$, where $A_0 \cap A_1 = \varnothing$ and $|A_0| = |A_1|$.
Let $\alpha$ be the partition whose blocks are $A_0$ and $A_1$, and let $\zeta:A_0 \to A_1$ be a bijection.
Let $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ be the partitions having as unique non-trivial block $A_0$ and $A_1$, respectively, and let $\beta$ be the partition whose blocks are the doubletons $\{a, \zeta(a)\}$, for $a \in A_0$.
This set of partitions generates the following sub-lattice of $\Pi(A)$:

Let $\pi$ be an atom of $\Pi(A)$ such that $\pi \leq \beta$.
Since $\alpha \prec \nabla_A$ and $\pi \nleq \alpha$, it follows that $\pi \vee \alpha = \nabla_A$, whence, using Claim 2,
\begin{align}
\pi \equiv_{\theta} \Delta_A
&\implies \nabla_A = \pi \vee \alpha \equiv_{\theta} \Delta_A \vee \alpha = \alpha\\
&\implies \beta = \nabla_A \wedge \beta \equiv_{\theta} \alpha \wedge \beta = \Delta_A\\
&\implies \nabla_A = \gamma_i \vee \beta \equiv_{\theta} \gamma_i \vee \Delta_A = \gamma_i\\
&\implies \Delta_A = \gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_1 \equiv_{\theta} \nabla_A.
\end{align}

This is extremely beautiful! It does seem the infinite case requires an entirely different approach, unique to the nature of infinity.    I will say, I think the $\xi_i$ should be entirely replaced by $\gamma_i$, as the argument doesn't need them, and the last two lines seem like they should have this replacement in order for the argument to make sense.

@Keith You are right and I don't know why I had added those two, unnecessarily. I'll edit it accordingly.
